# encrypting on javascript using ceaser cipher

Tags: javascript, encryption

My assignment is to simply encrypt and decrypt text in an input and output box using java script. Everything is already there for me but my job is to figure out how to write a Ceaser cipher. Can i get an algorithm of a simple one? Thank you.

Comment: refer http://beta.studentitzone.com/UI/viewarticle/Caesar-cipher-Encryption-and-Decryption-Program-in-Java

Answer (score 0):

You'll most likely want to implement the rot13 cipher, as it makes encryption/decryption the same algorithm.  With this, you increment a character by 13 to get the "encrypted" version.  If A is 1 and Z is 26, when you encrypt, A => N (1=>14) and Z => M (26=>13) Then to decrypt, N => A (14=>1); M => Z (13=>26).

```
function rot13(str) {
  return (str + '').replace(/[a-z]/gi, function (s) {
    return String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0) + (s.toLowerCase() < 'n' ? 13 : -13));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get a reference string with a..z+a..z and use Builders to construct encrypted string with a some logic like below, here message will be user entered string, ref will be a simple refrence string of a-z and currchar will store the index of current char we are going to replace...simple

```
for(int i=0;i<message.length();i++){
        currchar =ref.indexOf(message.charAt(i));
        currchar = currchar+shift;
        mEn.insert(i,ref.charAt(currchar));
    }
```